# A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget .Failed assertion: line 378 pos 10: 'data != null'

Tags: flutter, dart

Hi I am getting an error  I have tried looking through the "null(s)", but am unsure which one one is throwing the error.

Code:

```dart
class AssessmentForm extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  AssessmentFormState createState() => AssessmentFormState();
}
class AssessmentFormState extends State<AssessmentForm> {

  ValueNotifier selectFacility=ValueNotifier(null);
  ValueNotifier selectCommunity=ValueNotifier(null);

  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey();
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        elevation: 0,
        centerTitle: true,
        iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: AppColor.primarypurple),
        title: Text(
          getTranslated(context,'Assessment Form'),
          style: TextStyle(
              color: AppColor.primarypurple,
              fontSize: 20,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
        actions: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: DropdownButton<Language>(
              underline: SizedBox(),
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.language,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              onChanged: (Language language) {
                _changeLanguage(language);
              },
              items: Language.languageList()
                  .map<DropdownMenuItem<Language>>(
                    (lang) => DropdownMenuItem<Language>(
                  value: lang,
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text(
                        lang.flag,
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
                      ),
                      Text(lang.name)
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              )
                  .toList(),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(colors: [
            Color.fromRGBO(4, 131, 187, 0.21),
            Color.fromRGBO(210, 74, 187, 0.6),
            Color.fromRGBO(0, 132, 187, 0.2),
          ], begin: Alignment.bottomLeft, end: Alignment.topRight),
        ),
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 100),
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            RegisterShape(),
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 120),
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                      left: 20.0, right: 20, bottom: 10, top: 10),
                  child: Form(
                    key: _formKey,
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          getTranslated(context,'Current Site'),
                          style:TextStyle(fontSize: 20,fontWeight:FontWeight.bold),),
                        Row(
                          children: [
                            Expanded(child:
                            CheckboxListTile(
                              title:Text(
                                  getTranslated(context,'Facility'),
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize:14
                                  )),
                              controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading, value: firstCheck, onChanged: (bool value) {
                              setState(() {
                                firstCheck = value;
                                secondCheck = !value;
                              });
                            },
                            ),
                            ),
                            Expanded(child:
                            CheckboxListTile(
                              title: Text(
                                  getTranslated(context, 'Community'),
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize:14
                                  )),
                              controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading, value: secondCheck, onChanged: (bool value) {
                              setState(() {
                                firstCheck = !value;
                                secondCheck =value;
                              });
                            },
                            ),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
```

I am passing a null value through a widget in my title that is why it is giving the error.If said so i am passing a null value how do i use and pass the value that is not null in my title

Comment: Just check if the value is null first. If it is don't use `Text` or initialize the value to an empty string.

Comment: @moneer alhashim   This is the line  which is causing the error      title: Text( getTranslated(context,'Facility'), style: TextStyle( fontSize:14 )), – Rishail Siddiqui 12 mins ago    Delete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its because getTranslated() returns null.
try to:

```
title: Text(
       getTranslated(context, 'Community')?? "null",
       style: TextStyle(
            fontSize:14
       )
),
```

Answer (score 0):

As it is difficult to see where exactly line 378 is, have another look at all your text widgets and see if the text you have entered could be null, i.e. has no value.

Comment: This is the line 378:                                 title: Text(
                                  getTranslated(context,'Facility'),
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize:14
                                  )),